# Building External Identity Provider subproviders integration in Identity Server for 10.0 - 10.2 in Visual Studio 2022 for Author Access

Tags: identity-server

I am getting errors when compiling my subprovider implementation (Okta) with Identity Server in Visual Studio 2022.
I have followed all the instructions as described in https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/sitecore-experience-manager/use-the-sitecore-identity-server-as-a-federation-gateway.html
This is all working fine when compiling in Visual Studio 2019.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `Sitecore.Framework.Runtime.Build` SDK as outlined in the documentation only works for .Net Standard 2.1, which is not compatible with Visual Studio 2022 Build Tools.
The project must be built against Visual Studio 2019 Build Tools.

To build the project in Azure Pipelines, use the `windows-2019` agent.
To build the project inside a docker container, use `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-20211012` which contains Visual Studio 2019 Build tools.